# pdfgrep '\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}' vs '[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2}[-]?[0-9]{4}'

Tags: regex, linux, grep

`pdfgrep \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}` vs `[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2}[-]?[0-9]{4}`

1) Ran both of these but get only the results from the 2nd expression. 2) And 2nd one doesn't even catch all the results, it missed some when I did some spot checking. Any thoughts why? All SSNs are xxx-xx-xxx format.

Whole command:

```
find . -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep expression {} +
```

Update: 
1) See below
2) Some pdf were not searchable/not encoded properly

Comment: Escape the backslashes? Have the same rule about hyphens?

Comment: I think `\d` requires `-P`, but I don't know pdfgrep, just skimmed the documentation.

Comment: Also, quoting? `'\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}'`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, I used quotes, how would I add possible trailing and preceding spaces, I think that might be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *bug*. using

```
pdfgrep -P "\\w+" *.pdf
```

will return results corresponding to the `\w` range while doing the same with `\\d+` will not work.